# Facebook app inside users wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, html

Is posible to build a site like youtube, that when is shared in facebook users can run the app (in this case the video player) in the user wall without enter to the youtube page.

if is posible, this is only for videos?... can i get an interactive app, like a game do the same.

this can be only achieved using flash? or there is any way to do it using HTML5?

Thanks beforehand, any information will be apreciated.

Comment: I am betting Facebook coded that and you can not do it yourself and I am glad, I already get enough game requests about farms.

Comment: Hey im asking if is posible or not, why the down vote?... i really thinks is like you say but i have a client that is telling me that is posible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is available for any application and it's not limited to videos but any flash objects (strictly sandboxed without any access to parent document). Read more about posting to feed in [`user` object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts).

Use `source` field for [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) to provide link to flash movie/video. It is not stated in current documentation for user object that this field can be passed, but this is works, and it listed in post object documentation.

It is not possible to embed/share/publish HTML5 content on Facebook.